# How to map a response from http.get to a new instance of a typed object in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, http-get, observable

I'm trying to get an understanding in how to map the result from a service call to an object using http.get and Observables in Angular 2.

Take a look at this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/xylZgx)

In the method getPersonWithGetProperty I'm expecting to return an Observable of type PersonWithGetProperty. However! I can't access the property fullName. 
I guess that I would have to create a new instance of the class PersonWithGetProperty and map the response to this new object using the class constructor. But how do you do that in the method getPersonWithGetProperty?

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

export class PersonWithGetProperty {
  constructor(public firstName: string, public lastName: string){}

  get fullName(): string {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class PersonService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    getPersonWithGetProperty(): Observable<PersonWithGetProperty> {
        return this.http.get('data/person.json')
         .map((response: Response) => <PersonWithGetProperty>(response.json()));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't consider any of the solutions on StackOverflow to be a comprehensive solution to the problem.

So, I created an npm package angular-http-deserializer for this:
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-http-deserializer#usage

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is that you are coercing the parsed json to behave like the class.

Applying the `<PersonWithGetProperty>` isn't actually creating a new instance of `PersonWithGetProperty` it is just telling the compiler to shut up because you know what you are doing. If you want to actually create an instance `PersonWithGetProperty` you need to construct it with `new`.

Fortunately you are already half way there, just add another `map` after you have parsed the output:

```
@Injectable()
export class PersonService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    getPersonWithGetProperty(): Observable<PersonWithGetProperty> {
        return this.http.get('data/person.json')
         .map((response: Response) => response.json())
         .map(({firstName, lastName}) => new PersonWithGetProperty(firstName, lastName));
    }
}
```

**Edit**

For this to work you will need to make sure you are using for RxJS 5:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
```

If you want future safety you should be using the `pipe` syntax introduced in later versions of RxJS 5

```
// Either
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators'

return this.http.get('data/person.json').pipe(
  map((response: Response) => response.json()),
  map(({firstName, lastName}) => new PersonWithGetProperty(firstName, lastName))
);
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing things up for me!

Comment: What about if you have a very complex object or an object you cannot copy using just its constructor? An object without constructor, for example.

Comment: @CarlosAdrián then you use an object factory or you externalize the methods that you want to use on the object.

Comment: @paulpdaniels Can you provide an example of a complex object and this approach?