# in angular5, I cannot access methods in a foreach loop

Tags: angular

When I get an array of objects with httpClient, I can access properties of each object in the array, but I cannot access methods. I don't understand why, and how can I do this.

```
this.interventionService.getInterventions().subscribe(interventions =>
        { 
            interventions.forEach(it => {

               console.log(it.InterventionId); // property can be accessed
               console.log(it.myMethod()); // myMethod cannnot be accessed

               // I get an error: 'myMethod is not a function'

            });
        });
```

However, if I create a new object, I can access the methods:

```
var it = new Intervention();
it.myMethod(); // no error
```

Thanks for help

Comment: What's the interface of `Intervention`?

Comment: Also what is the implementation of `getInterventions()`?

Comment: You need something like: `... .getInterventions().map(items => items.map(i => new Intervention(i)).subscribe ...`

Comment: Use interfaces instead of classes for your models. Put the methods in services.

Comment: You have to manually map your object to your class. Angular httpClient just parses data to object. It knows nothing about your methods

Comment: See also related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310511/how-to-map-a-response-from-http-get-to-a-new-instance-of-a-typed-object-in-angul

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct `this` context for the method using `bind`.

```
this.interventionService.getInterventions().subscribe(interventions => {
  interventions.forEach(it => {
      it.myMethod.bind(it)();
  });
});
```

Comment: What if he also does something in the constructor... or has getters/setters on that Intervention class?